# Standard tools for URL normalization and standardization?

Tags: java, url, java-ee-7

I am java developer. Are there any standard tools for URL normalization and standardization?

> URL normalization (or URL canonicalization) is the process by which URLs are modified and standardized in a consistent manner. The goal of the normalization process is to transform a URL into a normalized or canonical URL so it is possible to determine if two syntactically different URLs are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the URI class:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#normalize%28%29

Its the standard tool and describes preety much everything.